# Getting value from an xml and storing it in a variable

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js

I have the following XML file stored in my hard disk.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<Message xmlns="http://schemas.sap.com/VE/Sandbox/2012/March" Version="SAP 3D Visual Enterprise Sandbox, version '1.0'">

  <Response Status="success">
    <Events>
      <MessageReportEvent Category="client" Id="1" Message="Start translating using CoreCAD Translator, version 9.0.0.0" Severity="info" TimeStamp="1447303476" UserData="&lt;Event Version=&quot;9.0.0.0&quot;/>&#xA;" UserId="1"/>
      <MessageReportEvent Category="client" Id="2" Message="Input file: C:\Thulitha\Work\PerformanceTest_to_Javascript\Data\TEST HARNESS - READ ONLY\AcisPerf\2.sat" Severity="info" TimeStamp="1447303476"/>
      <MessageReportEvent Category="client" Id="3" Message="Target location: c:\temp\tasks\acis\2.sat\" Severity="info" TimeStamp="1447303476"/>
      <MessageReportEvent Category="client" Id="4" Message="Temp location: c:\temp\tasks\acis\2.sat\" Severity="info" TimeStamp="1447303476"/>
      <MessageReportEvent Category="client" Id="5" Message="Schema location: C:\Thulitha\Work\PerformanceTest_to_Javascript\CoreCAD\schema" Severity="info" TimeStamp="1447303476"/>
      <MessageReportEvent Category="client" Id="6" Message="CAD Translator, Library Version 84" Severity="info" TimeStamp="1447303476"/>
      <MessageReportEvent Category="client" Id="7" Message="File format detected as ttAcis" Severity="info" TimeStamp="1447303476" UserData="&lt;Event FileType=&quot;ttAcis&quot;/>&#xA;" UserId="7"/>
      <MessageReportEvent Category="client" Id="8" Message="Reading Part: 2 (id: 1)" Severity="info" TimeStamp="1447303476"/>
      <MessageReportEvent Id="9" Message="Traversal in 0.059923595769666091" TimeStamp="1447303476"/>
      <MessageReportEvent Id="10" Message="Read assembly in 0.00097044839529173267" TimeStamp="1447303476"/>
      <MessageReportEvent Id="11" Message="Read components in 0.030274663085940956s" TimeStamp="1447303476"/>
      <MessageReportEvent Category="client" Id="12" Message="Loading using CADTranslator Succeeded" Severity="info" TimeStamp="1447303476"/>
    </Events>
  </Response>

</Message>
```

I need to get the value 0.059923595769666091 from this tag using JavaScript on node.js. How should I do it?

```
<MessageReportEvent Id="9" Message="Traversal in 0.059923595769666091" TimeStamp="1447303476"/>
```

Comment: Have a look at Cheerio.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[nodejs]+parse+xml

Comment: I could parse the whole xml file to variable named result.. The code is as follows

Comment: var fs = require('fs');
var xml2js = require('xml2js');

var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
fs.readFile('C:\\Temp\\tasks\\acis\\2.sat\\2.sat.response.xml', function(err, data) {
    parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);

      });
  });

Comment: How do I get the attribute?